# Set background color programmatically on RecyclerView item (certain element in item)

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have `ActivityGame` which has `TextView` that contains a par number. In that same `Activity` I have a `RecyclerView` and that `RecyclerView`, of course, contains multiple items. Those items have different par numbers.

For example, the Par number in `ActivityGame` is 3, now in `RecyclerView` items, let's say I have 1 item which has par number of 3, second has 2 and third has 4.

If an item's par number is the same as `ActivityGame`'s par number, then that items par numbers background should turn to grey. If item's par number is more than par number in the `ActivityGame`, then item's par number background should change to purple. And finally, if its smaller than `ActivityGame`'s par number, the item's par number background should change to blue.

Here is something I tried to do in the adapter, in order to make this work:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull GameViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.mTextPar.setText(currentItem.getText2());

    /** If persons par number is smaller than course par number, then change persons par number background to blue **/
    if (Integer.parseInt(holder.mTextPar.getText().toString()) < Integer.parseInt(ActivityGame.mHoleNm.getText().toString())) {
        holder.mTextPar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#255eba"));
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

This is what I thought would work, but it didn't, when I try to open `ActivityGame` where all this happens, my app crashes instantly.

I assume that `onBindViewHolder` is the correct place to make this happen, but I obviously have a wrong method. If you have a better idea where or how should I handle this, please share it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your app crashes then there is a corresponding entry in Logcat - please share this as well

Comment: It points to the line where I have my If

at com.example.frisbeecaddy.GameAdapter.onBindViewHolder(GameAdapter.java:89)

Comment: Please copy-paste the stack trace here.Usually it contains more than just a line number - I'm looking for something which ends with "Exception" but I'd also like to see the stack trace in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you do not have to call the `notifyDataSetChanged` each time you are setting the color of the background in the `onBindViewHolder` function.

Secondly, you need to implement all the conditions for your background colors in the `onBindViewHolder` function.

I would like to suggest an implementation like the following.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull GameViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.mTextPar.setText(currentItem.getText2());
    Integer parFromActivity = -1;
    if(ActivityGame.mHoleNm != null) 
        parFromActivity = Integer.parseInt(ActivityGame.mHoleNm.getText().toString());

    /** If persons par number is smaller than course par number, then change persons par number background to blue **/
    if (Integer.parseInt(holder.mTextPar.getText().toString()) < parFromActivity) {
        holder.mTextPar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#255eba"));
        // notifyDataSetChanged(); // We do not need this line
    } else if (Integer.parseInt(holder.mTextPar.getText().toString()) > parFromActivity) {
        holder.mTextPar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#800080")); // purple maybe
    } else {
        holder.mTextPar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#D3D3D3"));
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Edit:

Primarily I suppose that the view which is referenced from the activity is `null` when you are using this from your adapter. If that is the case, then you need to pass the value in some other way to the adapter.

As you have found the problem already, I am including this in my answer as well. The view was not having the `Integer` only. Hence the `Integer.parseInt(ActivityGame.mHoleNm.getText().toString()` was throwing the `ParseException` I suppose.

Comment: Ik that I need to do more conditions, but I didn't want to make more conditions before even this 1 is working. at the moment this 

if (Integer.parseInt(holder.mTextPar.getText().toString()) < Integer.parseInt(ActivityGame.mHoleNm.getText().toString()))

isn't working at all, with or without notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: That's where I needed  help with, to figure out why that isn't working

Comment: I have updated the answer. I think you need to check for `null` where you are trying to parse the value from the activity. Primarily I suppose that the view is null when you are referencing this from your adapter. If that is the case, then you need to pass the value in some other way to the adapter. If that is not the case, then please share your logcat so that we can investigate for further reasons.

Comment: Didn't work, that number could never be null tho, there is always number. Now I figured out that when I changed Integer.parseInt(ActivityGame.mHoleNm.getText().toString()) manually (just to try) to 3 it worked, so for some reason my adapter cannot get the number from activity correctly...

Comment: Yes, that's what I was referring to. You need to have another way of passing that number from your activity to the adapter. A `public static` variable declared in your activity might work just fine.

Comment: oh god, I just found the problem, I have more stuff in that mHoleNm than just the number, thats why it wont take it....

Comment: I see. Then you have got a `ParseException` in your logcat. Good to know that your problem is solved. :)

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: quick question out of topic, how to instead of using colors for background how could I use some custom drawable?

Answer (score 0):

You should not have static widgets in your activity. Instead, you should pass the par number as a parameter to the adapter constructor so you do not have to declare a static method in your activity to get the par value.

If the par value might change live, then add a method to your adapter to take the new par value and then refresh the adapter items. That method would be called from the activity, whenever the par value changed.